Expectation of binomial random variable
Having trouble understanding something I read in a paper recently.
Say we have $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(N,p).$ The paper states:
$$E[X \mid N,p] = Np$$ (so far so good)
and
$$E[X] = \mu p$$
Where is $p$ in the second line coming from, if $\mu$ is defined as $Np$ for $\operatorname{Binomial}(N,p)$?

The first notation suggests both $N$ and $p$ are random variables, so perhaps $\mu$ is related to them.  Since "$\mu$" has no inherent or commonly understood meaning, surely it is defined or described elsewhere in that paper. I think we need a more complete statement of the context of that paper in order to understand your question.

It seems that what must have been meant was
$$
X\mid N \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(N,p)
$$
and $\mu=\operatorname E(N).$
In that case you have $\operatorname E(X\mid N) = Np$ and then
$$
\operatorname E(X) = \operatorname E(\operatorname E(X\mid N)) = \operatorname E(Np) = p\operatorname E(N) = p\mu.
$$
